# How to get file names from strings in a file?

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which contains file names and other text.  If I filter the file with this:

```
Get-Content .\Movies.txt | Select-String volume
```

I get the output below.  How can I modify the above command so the output is just the file names?

```
/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Poltergeist (2015).mp4
/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Goosebumps (2015).mp4
/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to see how you made the text file in the first place, as there is probably a better way to store/extract the data you're after. However, to address your specific question I propose two options. If you can provide more detail of what the "other text" is, then this answer may be improved.

**Option 1**

Use split on '/` and grab the last element.

```
'/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4'.Split('/')[-1]

Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4
```

or

```
('/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4' -split '/')[-1]

Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4
```

**Option 2**

Use a regex pattern to extract the filename.

```
'/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4' -replace '^.+/(?=.+)'

Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4
```

To apply any of these in a loop you can use the `Line` property of the returned match.

```
Get-Content .\Movies.txt | Select-String volume | foreach {$_.line.Split('/')[-1]}
```

However the switch statement can both read the file and process line by line.

```
Switch -Regex -File (".\Movies.txt")
{
    'volume' {$_.Split('/')[-1]}
}

Poltergeist (2015).mp4
Goosebumps (2015).mp4
Hotel Transylvania 2 (2015).mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I just need to add a for-each to use what you suggested.

Comment: Yes in its current standing. I’d recommend a switch statement to avoid both get-content and the foreach loop but without knowing the other text that might not be the right approach.

Comment: So the Switch statement will only select lines containing 'volume'?  That is interesting.  
-Thanks

Comment: Correct if you use -Regex flag.

Answer (score 1):

I can use `Split-Path` here:

```
(Get-Content .\Movies.txt | Select-String volume) | ForEach {split-path "$($_)" -Leaf}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I was trying something similar but did not use the ForEach loop.  Can you tell me, what is the $ before the ($_)?

Comment: $_ is the current value in pipeline of iterating object

Comment: I understand what $_ is, I don't understand why it is enclosed in the $()

Answer (score 1):

Here's three more ;)

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName('/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Poltergeist (2015).mp4')
```

and

```
'/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Poltergeist (2015).mp4'.Substring('/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Poltergeist (2015).mp4'.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

and

```
'/volume1/Media Library/Movies/Poltergeist (2015).mp4' -replace '.*/(.+)$', '$1'
```